# Order of study? Rudin, Spivak, Munkres?

Tags: analysis, soft-question

I'm currently taking an analysis course at a top 10 four year university in which we use Baby Rudin as our primary text.

I was curious to know the order in which I should continue my studies. That is, should I study Rudin then Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds then Munkres Topology? Or, should I study Rudin and Spivak concurrently and then Munkres? Or some variation? I already have exposure to topology, just never in a formal course.

I'm trying to broaden my mathematical foundation as much as possible in the next year and a half before I leave high school, so I'd like to know the different analysis/topology paths to consider, and **why**.

Comment: I've never used Spivak, but in general you should learn point set topology before learning about manifolds.  You can start working from Munkres after you cover the chapter in Rudin on metric spaces.

Comment: @Seth I know enough topology to study manifolds, however.

Comment: Personally I'd do chapters 2-5 in Munkres before Spivak.  If you already know chapters 2-5, then theres no real reason to use Munkres at all, unless you have a particular interset in point set topology.  For algebraic topology you might want to use Hatcher instead.

Comment: @Seth Is Hatcher really the best for algebraic? I read the first chapter and the formatting was a bit rough but the content seemed pretty good.

Comment: The only algebraic topology books I've used are Hatcher and Munkres.  Munkres has the advantage of being more rigorous and detailed at times, but I think Hatcher is overall better in that it presents a better narrative and ordering of the material, plus it eventually gets to much more advanced material (you will probably reference long after you have worked through it, while Munkres not so much).

Comment: Hatcher is very well-liked.

Answer (score 1):

As someone who studied Baby Rudin in high school, I suggest studying the first 4 chapters of Baby Rudin before moving on to Munkres. When you start studying Munkres, you can go straight into the second chapter (Topological spaces).